# Missing Database Diagrams option in SQL Server Management Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I am trying to create a database diagram for a database that I have recently been given access to. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19 to access the server.

The server is using SQL Server version 2019 (v15.0). I have multiple local databases on my device that are running on SQL Server 2022 (v16.0) and I can generate database diagrams on all of them without any issues.

I am not sure what to look out for in terms understanding why I can't create database diagrams. Is it because of the SQL Server version? Or more likely is it because of the permissions I have been given, and if so, what permissions should I request from the DBA?

I have limited access to the database as I am not the administrator. I searched the SQL Server Management Studio interface to see if the option to create a diagram has been moved somewhere else. However, this seems unlikely as I can still go to the same place to generate the diagrams on my local databases.

Comment: There's no such thing as SSMS 2019. Do you mean SSMS *19*,  which came out in 2022.

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/understand-database-diagram-ownership-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver16)?